# Getting wrong answer when counting array in c

Tags: c, arrays, count

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int countArrayChars(char *strArray[]){
    int i=0;
    while (strArray[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *dog[] = {"dog"};
    countArrayChars(dog);
```

For some reason, it prints "5".

Shouldn't it print 3?
I even tried to put \0 after the "g".

Comment: --> `while (strArray[0][i] != '\0'){`

Comment: or `char dog[] = {"dog"};` ..`int countArrayChars(char strArray[]){`

Comment: Like BLUEPIXY said, strArray is an array of strings so strArray[0] is a pointer to the first string in the array and strArray[1] doesn't exist.  What you are iterating is the bytes in the address of the pointer to the string.

Comment: Can you give a quick/simple explanation of why having two [ ] [ ] fixed it?
Sorry, sort of a beginner.

Comment: Nvm, multidimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare array of string and initialize it with `dog`.

```
char *dog[] = {"dog"};
```

Actually it represented as

```
dog[0] = "Dog";     //In your case only element index with 0.
...............
...............
dog[n] = "tiger";   //If there Have n+1 element
```

Hence  your array size is 1. Which hold constant string `dog`. To access it you should use `dog[0]`.

So without less modification you can use your code as:

```
int countArrayChars(char *strArray[])
{
    int i=0;
    while (strArray[0][i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *dog[] = {"dog"};
    countArrayChars(dog);
}
```

Or if you want to declare a string use

```
char *dog = "dog";
```

or

```
char dog[] = "dog";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


int countArrayChars(char *strArray){
    int i=0;
    while (strArray[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *dog[] = "dog";
    countArrayChars(dog);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to disagree, it compiles and runs and gives 3.

Comment: Could you try a C compiler ? That's what I am using, not C++